# "backrefrence conditions" in python "regex" and "re" module does not work as expected

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match only North American numbers existing in a string; **(123)456-7890 and 123-456-7890 are both acceptable presentation formats for North American phone numbers, meaning anyother pattern should not match.**

Note: **python3.7 and pycharm Editor is being used.**

Here are phone numbers represented in a string:

`123-456-7890
(123)456-7890
(123)-456-7890
(123-456-7890
1234567890
123 456 7890`

I tried to use `(\()?\d{3}(?(1)\)|-)\d{3}-\d{4}` regex which indeed uses backrefrence conditionals to match the desired phone numbers, **Below the python code Is included:**

```
import regex
st = """
123-456-7890
(123)456-7890
(123)-456-7890
(123-456-7890
1234567890
123 456 7890
"""
pat = regex.compile(r'(\()?\d{3}(?(1)\)|-)\d{3}-\d{4}', regex.I)
out = pat.findall(st)
print(out)
```

> Output using findall method: ['', '(', '']
>
> Output using search(st).group() method which returns just the first match: 123-456-7890
>
> Matches should be : 
>                       `123-456-7890
>                    (123)456-7890`

***My question is: Why does findall method which should return The matched patterns flawlessly as it does in [regex 101 website](https://regex101.com/), Now does return such irritating results like `['', '(', '']` ?***

I have tried the regex in [regex 101 website](https://regex101.com/) and it works perfectly, but does not here.

Note: **I am using sams teach yourself regular expressions book and in page 134 The best solution for this problem is suggested and the above is it's python implementation.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is correct but if you use `findall` then it automatically prints all captured groups. Better to use `finditer` and print `.group()` or `.group(0)`:

```
>>> pat = regex.compile(r'^(\()?\d{3}(?(1)\)|-)\d{3}-\d{4}$', regex.M)
>>> for m in pat.finditer(st):
...     print (m.group())
...
123-456-7890
(123)456-7890
```

Comment: can you please tell me how does findall method return such `['', '(', '']` out put actually why such result is returned !?, because it's been an enigma for me seriously

Comment: If one or more groups are present in the pattern, then `findall` by design returns a list of groups.

Answer (score 1):

Use re.finditer:
`print(list(pat.finditer(st)))`